# Asterisk ARI call from external to external

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx

I want to make a call using Asterisk 13 ARI from my mobile number to another mobile number.
I have tried different calls but all return "**Allocation failed**" response:

```
endpoint:my_mobile_number,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-trunk

endpoint:SIP/my_mobile_number,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-trunk

endpoint:SIP/my_mobile_number,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-external

endpoint:my_mobile_number,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-external

etc.
```

How can I initiate a call from my mobile phone to another mobile phone using ARI?

**EDIT**

arheops answer helped me find the working code:

```
endpoint:Local/my_mobile_number@from-internal,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-internal,priority:1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi,  I do have same question and as I am new to Asterisk ARI.  I didn't get how above answer will be implemented.  I am using Python requests to use ARI api, but didn't find any of the API that will originate a call to extension, or other Softphone configured on Asterisk.

If you have enough time, can you share an example in any languages such as perl, or javascript or python.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortanly you can't use ARI without understanding asterisk internals. You need read some book for beginners.

```
endpoint:Local/my_mobile_number@out_context,extension:other_mobile_number,context:out_context,priority:1

endpoint:SIP/my_mobile_number@myprovider_sip,extension:other_mobile_number,context:out_context,priority:1
```

both variant have be working

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me find the working code: endpoint:Local/my_mobile_number@from-internal,extension:other_mobile_number,context:from-internal,priority:1

Comment: Any book that you recommend for this?